# My linked list in ruby is giving me the desired output and does not throw any error

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures

My linked list is failing the given test and it's not throwing any errors.

The question:

Create your own LinkedList  class for storing integers which should include two methods:

`add(number)` - Add a new Node to the end of the list with a value of a number. Nothing needs to be returned.

`get(index)` - Return the value of the Node at position `index` in the List.

Example

This is an example of a test case:

```
list = LinkedList.new   
list.add(3)
list.add(5)
puts list.get(1)
  #=> 5
```

The 2 add operations create the list: `[3, 5]`.
The get operation, gets the number located at position `1`.

My solution:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node      
  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)  
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end

class LinkedList
  #setup head and tail
  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end  

  def add(number)    
    this_node = Node.new(number)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = this_node
    else
      current = @head
      until current.next_node.nil?
        current = current.next_node
      end    
      current.next_node = this_node    
    end    
  end

  def get(index)   
    current = @head    
    index.times do    
      current = current.next_node
    end    
    return current    
  end    
end
```

Test here:

```
list = LinkedList.new
list.add(3)
list.add(5)
puts list.get(1)
  #=> 5
```

When I run my solution in ripple.it, it fails all the test.

And when I run it on code editor with puts, I get:

```
#<Node:0x000055cb85579238>
```

And with `p`, I get:

```
#<Node:0x0000557a796dfcd8 @value=3, @next_node=#<Node:0x0000557a796dfbe8 @value=5, @next_node=nil>>
```

I need clarification as I'm still very new to data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Shoud your title read, "...is *not* giving me..."? It now reads that your code is behaving correctly. See the selected answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) that explains how to format code at SO.

Comment: Could you show us the original problem text? Do you have access to the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just one error in your code. The line `return current` in `get` should be:

```
current.value
```

`current` is an instance of `Node`. `current.value` is the value of the instance variable `@value` for that instance.

`return` is not needed when it is the last calculation performed by the method.

You don't use the instance variable `@tail`. It is not used because yours is a [singly-linked list](https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/08/ruby-linked-list/), as opposed to a *doubly-linked list*. You therefore can remove it.